# Magical disappearing emails in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a computer in a room in which I use to check emails on the Outlook software for web browsers. The email requires me to log into the domain with a username and password, which is normal. When it opens up, I am supposed to be able to read my email.

However.

I once checked my email on a different computer on our network, and it looked like it worked normally. When I went to check my email back on my regular computer there were no messages, despite the fact that I had just had them on the other computer. Furthermore, when I recieve emails, they wont usually appear on my normal computer now. What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and make a few assumptions.  First, that you setup your email as a POP3 on the second computer thus whenever an email is sent it may be being "downloaded" to the other computer.  Secondly, I'm also assuming that you are using a cloud based email provider (gmail, live, etc) and not an exchange server.

I would check your outlook on the second computer and see if the emails are there.  If so, the you have a few options:

1. You can un-install outlook on one computer and just use the other.
2. Switch both outlook email accounts to IMAP instead of POP3 to prevent "disappearances"